# Pandas - Find and Replace values starting with a '<'

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have values in a data frame with certain cells starting '< 101' and certain cells with '< 2' and some with '< 1'. I am trying to write regex using a Pandas Dataframe to find those cells and replace them entirely with the value '0.0'.

Here is what I have:

```
df_new2=df_new.replace('(?=<)','0', regex=True)
```

The above code simply adds a '0' in front of '< 101' 
with this output '0< 101'.

What I am looking for is an output that finds the '< 101' and replaces it with '0'. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df_new2 = df_new.replace('^.*<.*$', '0', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'^<.*$'`? Note the `$` is redundant. See *values **starting** with a '<'*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `'^.*<.*$'` is less strict and handles the string `'<'` being anywhere in the cell.